# make the multiselect value as json format

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I have the multiselect box nd I want to get the value and make it in below json format.multiselectbox value is an array value.

```
{"username":{"user1":"user1","user2":"user2","user3":"user3"},
 "geo":{"geo1":"geo1","geo2":"geo2"},
 "week":{"week2":"week2","week4":"week4"} 
}
```

```js
$(".go").click(function(){

   var filter =[];
  var username=$( "#username" ).val();
  var geo=$( "#geo" ).val();
  var week=$( "#week" ).val();
  var team=$( "#team" ).val();
  filter[username]=username;
  filter[geo]=geo;
  filter[week]=week;
  filter[team]=team;
  
  console.log(filter[username]);
  var userarr=JSON.stringify(filter);
  console.log(userarr);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-popup" id="filter" style="display: block;">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <select id="username" multiple=""><option selected="true" disabled="">Username</option><option>user1</option><option>user2</option><option>user3</option><option>user4</option></select>
 <select id="geo" multiple=""><option selected="true" disabled="">Geo</option><option>chennai</option><option>covai</option><option>hydrabad</option><option>cochin</option><option>mumbai</option></select>
 <select id="week" multiple=""><option selected="true" disabled="">Weeks</option><option>week1</option><option>week2</option><option>week3</option><option>week4</option></select>
 <select id="team" multiple=""><option selected="true" disabled="">Teams</option><option>Java</option><option>Lamp</option><option>Oracle</option><option>Sales</option></select>
 <button class="go">GO</button>
 </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dyx8wa9p/1/

Comment: Within`"geo":{"geo1":"geo1","geo2":"geo2"},` what does `geo1 and geo2` in key and value represents?

Comment: yes key and velue is same

Comment: I can't see that in the html code you provided

Comment: geo1 and geo2 isselected value in multoiselect

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dyx8wa9p/1/

Comment: The JSON structure you are trying to generate is a very suboptimal representation of the data. Do you have control over it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary issue is `var filter =[];`. You are setting filter to be an ARRAY. You want it to be an OBJECT with specific key names.

```js
$(".go").click(function(){
  const filter = {
    username: $("#username").val(),
    geo: $("#geo").val(),
    week: $("#week").val(),
    team: $("#team").val(),
  };

  const otherFilterFormat = Object.keys(filter).reduce((a, c) => {
    a[c] = filter[c].reduce((x, y) => {
      x[y] = y;
      return x;
    }, {});
    return a;
  }, {});

  console.log(filter, otherFilterFormat);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-popup" id="filter" style="display: block;">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <select id="username" multiple=""><option selected="true" disabled="">Username</option><option>user1</option><option>user2</option><option>user3</option><option>user4</option></select>
 <select id="geo" multiple=""><option selected="true" disabled="">Geo</option><option>chennai</option><option>covai</option><option>hydrabad</option><option>cochin</option><option>mumbai</option></select>
 <select id="week" multiple=""><option selected="true" disabled="">Weeks</option><option>week1</option><option>week2</option><option>week3</option><option>week4</option></select>
 <select id="team" multiple=""><option selected="true" disabled="">Teams</option><option>Java</option><option>Lamp</option><option>Oracle</option><option>Sales</option></select>
 <button class="go">GO</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: value is in the format {"user1":"user1","user2":"user2"} instead of [
    "user1",
    "user2"
  ]

Comment: I have added an additional mutation to get the result you want. However, I do not suggest using that data format.

Comment: reduce filter[c].reduce is not a function in my js file